# Python regular expression or substring to find strings in a file

Tags: python-2.7

I am parsing a file searching for strings in format alphanumeric#hexadecimal till 32bit. 
e.g. `1234#ffy8G`  or `1234#fhfj45` or `ab23#897hg`.

The prefix number is always of  4 characters. 
I am not sure if i need to use regex or substring but as the prefix string is am mix of alphanumeric characters, i think regex is a better option

my pattern =`^[\w]{4}#[a-zA-Z0-9].*`

how do i check for 4 chars only string prefix in the pattern. Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: but with split, I cant check number of characters of prefix. I want to extract only string prefix which has 4 alphanumeric characters in it. So i thought i could control this with regex pattern

Comment: I have also tried re.search('(?<=[0-9].*#\w.*', '1245#afdjkjfd') but could not find   a match